# viewDidLoad doesn't get called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code in my view controller implementation `BNRDetailViewController.m`:

```
//
//  BNRDetailViewController.m
//  Homepwner
//
//  Created by Dylan Jhaveri on 4/22/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Dylan Jhaveri. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BNRDetailViewController.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"
#import "BNRImageStore.h"

@implementation BNRDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidload
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view did load");
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"view did appear");
}

@end
```

When I launch the simulator and navigate to this `DetailView` in the simulator I see the log for "view will appear", but I never see the log for "view did load".

This is the code from the ItemsViewController, a subclass of UITableViewController:

```
#import "BNRItemsViewController.h"
#import "BNRDetailViewController.h"
#import "BNRItemStore.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"

@interface BNRItemsViewController () <UITableViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation BNRItemsViewController
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//init detailViewController and set `item`
BNRDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[BNRDetailViewController alloc] init];
NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
detailViewController.item = items[indexPath.row];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

P.S. I am using a NIB (.xib) file for this view `BNRDetailViewController.xib`.  This NIB file has the file's owner set to `BNRDetailViewController`.

The entire .m file is here: https://gist.github.com/dylanjha/09c234adf536667d9564

EDIT: added `super` calls and `@implementation`, `@end` and `#import`

Comment: You are missing `[super viewDidLoad]` and [super viewWillAppear] calls.

Comment: Try copying and pasting the REAL code. What you posted is fake code that doesn't even compile.

Comment: right, but weather or not I put the super calls, this should still get called, right?

Comment: Also post _how_ you "navigate" to it, navigation controller, modal view controller, tab controller, etc.?

Comment: @rmaddy sorry about the "fake" code. amended

Comment: Don't just update the question with bits and pieces. Seriously, *copy* and *paste* your actual code from your actual .m file. You may have something in your .m file causing the problem that isn't being repeated by simply typing similar code into your question.

Comment: I did copy and paste bits from my .m file, you're suggesting I copy and paste my entire .m file?

Comment: No, not the whole file. But I was left with the impression that the code in your answer was simply typed into the question instead of really copied and pasted from your .m file. If the `viewDidLoad` method is really copy and pasted then you are good.

Comment: oops, sorry, added the whole file, now removed bits of it.. here is a link to the entire file if its helpful for anyone else: https://gist.github.com/dylanjha/09c234adf536667d9564

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I'm an objective c n00b

Comment: Echoing what @Rich said, how are you navigating to this detail controller? Are you actually using the view controller, or are you simply loading the nib?

Comment: just added the navigation details @Rich, let me know if that information is incomplete.

Comment: Out of interest, if you do `detailViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` directly after `BNRDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[BNRDetailViewController alloc] init];` does the `viewDidLoad` get called?

Comment: @Rich no.  I do see the redColor on the background, but viewDidLoad still does not get called.

Comment: `- (void)viewDidload` should be `- (void)viewDidLoad` (uppercase `L`).

Comment: @Anna, I think you nailed it.

Comment: @Anna thank you, add that as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: This is why you should post your actual code from the start...!

Comment: @Rich from the very beginning I copy/pasted the methods.  All that was "fake" about my code that wouldn't compile is I was missing `@interface` and `@end`

Comment: @dylanjha, Don't worry about it.  Accept matt's answer.  It's no big deal.

Comment: Thank you everyone... appreciated

Comment: @dylanjha Sorry but you did post fake code until your last edit. Looking back at the edit history of the question shows you posted `viewDidLoad` (big "L") until you finally posted `viewDidload` (little "L") on your 4th edit.

Comment: You're right, I was copy/pasting from the wrong file `BNRItemsViewController`, you can see I put it in the `@implementation`.  My apologies.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `viewDidload` is not the same as `viewDidLoad`. The runtime will call the latter if it exists - but not the former, which is what you have.

Comment: This is correct.  Thank you.  @Anna got this slightly before you in a comment so I am going to award it to her if she posts her answer.

Comment: Quite right! I didn't look at the comments so it's just chance.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidload` l must be capital. it will be `-(void)viewDidLoad`